# Python(Numpy)- df apply error - IndexError: tuple index out of range

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

```
from pandas import DataFrame,Series
import numpy

def avg_bronze_medal():
    countries=['Russian Fed','Norway','Canada']
    gold=[13,11,10]
    silver=[11,5,10]
    bronze=[9,10,5]
    medal_counts={'country_name':Series(countries),'gold':Series(gold),'silver':Series(silver),'bronze':Series(bronze)}
    df=DataFrame(medal_counts)
    print df
    print df['gold'].apply(numpy.mean, axis=1)
```

Last line is giving error as "IndexError: tuple index out of range". I need to use apply function in data frame and it should get average of columns gold,bronze and silver. In above example, I used only gold column. Please help me in fixing the error.

Comment: `df['gold'].mean()`

Comment: Try this:  `df.drop(['country_name'],1).mean()`

Comment: Or, drop the `axis` kwag, or set it to 0...

Comment: @Kartik, you are right - it doesn't make sense to count average (among gold, silber, bronze) number of medals per country...

Comment: Yeah that's what I was on about. But, I deleted my comment because who know why the OP needs something we find strange computed...

Answer (score 0):

To get the mean of all three columns at the same time:

```
df[['gold', 'bronze', 'silver']].mean(axis=1)
```

But it confuses me as to why you would need the average medals awarded in the tournament... But I guess you need it for some reason!

---

Some additional notes the OP should be aware of:

[`.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) is a method that works on rows or columns (default). If you call `df.apply(func)` the function, `func` will be applied to all columns, one column at a time. `df.apply(func, axis=1)` will apply `func` to all rows, one at a time. In case of `pd.Series` since there is only one column, `.apply` always works on rows. `.apply` is useful if you have a [complex custom function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#flexible-apply) that you need to apply to either rows or columns. Some statistical measures, such as sum, mean, standard deviation, are [common](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#cython-optimized-aggregation-functions) and have vectorized functions of their own. Therefore one can directly call them, like in the answer above.

Please read the docs linked in the above paragraph for further information.